# asreml in R, package download

Tags: windows, r

I am running R in Windows (R 2.14.2), and I wanted to use ASReml within R:

```
library(asreml)

Error in library(asreml) : there is no package called ‘asreml’
```

Is there a new version of the package or another way I should follow to download and use it?

Comment: You have to install it first.

Comment: You haven't really answered the question and this question is most certainly NOT a duplicate.

To obtain asreml-r, visit this page:
http://www.vsni.co.uk/downloads/asreml

Click on the link to email support and ask for a trial license (or free license if you are eligible).